# Magento Commerce Cloud Docker Deployment - Invalid entity_type specified: customer

Tags: installation, docker, deployment, magento-cloud

I have an existing Magento Commerce Cloud Project which I want to deploy to a Docker environment.
Running `./bin/magento-docker ece-deploy` I get the following error:

```
Running "deploy" hook.
[2021-07-08 11:36:54] INFO: Starting scenario(s): scenario/deploy.xml (magento/ece-tools version: 2002.1.6, magento/magento2-base version: 2.4.2-p1)
[2021-07-08 11:36:55] NOTICE: Reset the contents of the opcache
[2021-07-08 11:36:55] INFO: Deleting flag: var/.deploy_is_failed
[2021-07-08 11:36:55] NOTICE: Starting pre-deploy.
[2021-07-08 11:36:55] INFO: Updating cache configuration.
[2021-07-08 11:36:55] INFO: Skip copying directory ./var/view_preprocessed.
[2021-07-08 11:36:55] INFO: Clearing ./var/view_preprocessed
[2021-07-08 11:36:55] INFO: Clearing redis cache: default
[2021-07-08 11:36:56] INFO: Clearing redis cache: page_cache
[2021-07-08 11:36:56] WARNING: [2026] Cannot copy directory /app/init/app/etc. Directory does not exist.
[2021-07-08 11:36:56] WARNING: [2026] Cannot copy directory /app/init/pub/media. Directory does not exist.
[2021-07-08 11:36:56] NOTICE: Recoverable directories were copied back.
[2021-07-08 11:36:56] INFO: Set Magento application mode to 'production'
[2021-07-08 11:36:56] NOTICE: End of pre-deploy.
[2021-07-08 11:36:56] NOTICE: Enabling Maintenance mode
[2021-07-08 11:37:47] WARNING: Command maintenance:enable finished with an error. Creating a maintenance flag file manually.
[2021-07-08 11:37:47] INFO: Disable cron
[2021-07-08 11:37:47] INFO: Trying to kill running cron jobs and consumers processes
[2021-07-08 11:37:48] INFO: Running Magento cron and consumers processes were not found.
[2021-07-08 11:37:48] NOTICE: Validating configuration
[2021-07-08 11:37:51] INFO: Version of service 'rabbitmq' is not detected
[2021-07-08 11:37:51] INFO: Version of service 'redis' is 5.0
[2021-07-08 11:37:51] INFO: Version of service 'redis-session' is not detected
[2021-07-08 11:37:51] INFO: Version of service 'elasticsearch' is 7.7.1
[2021-07-08 11:37:51] INFO: Version of service 'mariadb' is 10.4
[2021-07-08 11:37:53] INFO: Checking if db exists and has tables
[2021-07-08 11:37:53] NOTICE: Fix configuration with given suggestions:
[2021-07-08 11:37:53] WARNING: Cannot read contents from file "/app/pub/errors/local.xml" Warning!file_get_contents(/app/pub/errors/local.xml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
[2021-07-08 11:37:53] NOTICE: End of validation
[2021-07-08 11:37:53] INFO: Checking existence of encryption key
[2021-07-08 11:37:53] INFO: Checking if db exists and has tables
[2021-07-08 11:37:53] NOTICE: Starting install.
[2021-07-08 11:37:53] INFO: Installing Magento.
[2021-07-08 11:39:12] INFO: Set flag: var/.deploy_is_failed
[2021-07-08 11:39:12] ERROR: [116] The command "/bin/bash -c "set -o pipefail; php ./bin/magento setup:install -n --ansi --no-interaction --cleanup-database --session-save='db' --use-secure-admin='1' --use-rewrites='1' --currency='USD' --base-url='http://magento2.docker/' --base-url-secure='https://magento2.docker/' --backend-frontname='admin' --language='en_US' --timezone='America/Los_Angeles' --db-host='db' --db-name='magento2' --db-user='magento2' --db-password='******' --admin-user='admin' --admin-firstname='Admin' --admin-lastname='Username' --admin-email='admin@example.com' --admin-password='******' --search-engine='elasticsearch7' --elasticsearch-host='elasticsearch' --elasticsearch-port='9200' | tee -a /app/var/log/install_upgrade.log"" failed. In Config.php line 449:

  Invalid entity_type specified: customer
```

Can anybody help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have used below command from this url and solved for me.

> ./bin/magento-docker ece-redeploy

https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/docker/docker-quick-reference.html